# Zeit now: how to remove alias?

Tags: vercel

After following Zeit's tutorial on using their now CLI, I created a subdomain by calling a bare "now" command, and then created an alias for that subdomain by calling "now alias AUTOGENERATED_NAME MY_CUSTOM_NAME"

Later on, I tried to delete both of those, by calling "now alias rm MY_CUSTOM_NAME" and "now rm AUTOGENERATED_NAME".

The autogenerated url gives 404 now as expected, but the name I picked earlier for MY_CUSTOM_NAME is still online and serves the content that was uploaded earlier.

Zeit's online dashboard has "You removed alias MY_CUSTOM_NAME" in the history. However, it's still online...

How do I remove it/kill it?

Note that if I run "now ls" in the shell, it says "0 total deployments found under MY_ZEIT_USRENAME". And yet, that aliased url still shows that last deployment...

Comment: You might want to contact Zeit support. It sounds like you did everything right here and its a bug on their end.

Comment: in the end, I found out that it just expires on its own after you wait for long enough.

Answer (score 1):

`now alias rm alias-to-be-deleted`

READ: https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/removing-alias~9856d8a6-f88d-4ddc-af5a-90bd7469bb5c?m=MTUzNTg4MDcyNzc5Mw==

Answer (score -1):

This happens is because the **deployment** still exists.
To remove the deployment go to your [zeit dashboard](https://zeit.co/dashboard)
Click on the project name, then click the 3 dots to the right of the deployment. You will see a popup menu to delete the deployment.
You could also go to the project settings and delete the entire project if you want.

Comment: If you are downvoting this, you probably didnt read the question. Make sure you remove the alias with `now alias rm PUTYOURALIASHERE`